# Return base64 of a File object using FileReader.readAsDataURL()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

I have a JS File object that I need to convert in base64 value and return that value in a JSON object. I'm using FileReader.readAsDataURL() but since it's asynchronous, It seems that I don't get base64 value 'on time'. I'm calling callback function that needs obj. data value, but it's undefined.

```
function mapFileData(file, callback) {
    var obj = {};
        obj.name = file.filename;
        obj.size = file.fileSize;
        obj.type = file.fileType;
        obj.data = getBase64(file);
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // file object with undefined 'data' value 
    callback(obj);
}

function getBase64(file) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    if (file) {
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        return event.target.result;
    };
}
```

I don't really know how to make `obj.data` value available when I call  `callback(obj)`. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the callback syntax to `async/await` syntax, so you can `await` the file to be converted to base64.

For example.

```
async function mapFileData(file, callback) {
    var obj = {};
     const base64 = await getBase64(file);
        obj.name = file.filename;
        obj.size = file.fileSize;
        obj.type = file.fileType;
        obj.data = base64
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
    callback(obj); // it would be better to return the obj here and `await` this function in the caller, instead of using callback syntax
}

function getBase64(file) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    if (file) {
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fileReader.onload = function(event) {
        resolve(event.target.result);
      };
    })
}
```

Also, I suggest removing callback syntax from `mapFileData` function and converting it to `async/await` syntax too.

**UPDATE**
This is the solution with `Callback` syntax.

```
function mapFileData(file, callback) {
    
     const base64Callback = function(res) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = file.filename;
        obj.size = file.fileSize;
        obj.type = file.fileType;
        obj.data = res
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
        callback(obj);
     }
     getBase64(file, base64Callback)
}

function getBase64(file, callback) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    if (file) {
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
      callback(event.target.result);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems like a good solution. But is there another solution that doesn't use `async/await`? I would like to make it compatible for older browsers.

Comment: @peterremec, I just update the answer with `callback` syntax, please check.